# ¿Como llamar a una función ajax después de hacer submit desde una función javascript de validación?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Tengo un formulario de login que se carga con ajax de javascript. Cuando hago click en enviar formulario, entra en la función que valida los campos, si todo es correcto hace el submit y entra bien en la consulta php en la que si el usuario existe debería enseñarme de nuevo la vista en la que estaba pero con la vista ajax cargada. 
¿Alguien tiene idea de como hacerlo? Al hacer submit, recarga la página con header("Location:catalogo_index.php") pero yo necesito que recargue con la función comprar().
Agradezco de antemano!!

La vista principal:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <title>Catálogo</title>

    <!--   Bootstrap  -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark sticky-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Catálogo Lafcarr</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navb" aria-expanded="true">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div id="navb" class="navbar-collapse collapse hide">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
<a class='nav-link' href='#' onclick='peticion_login();'><span class='fas fa-sign-in-alt'></span> Login</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

    <div id="login"></div>
    <div id="comprar"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

La vista ajax de formulario:

```
<div class="container  entrar" style="margin-top:20px; margin-bottom:10px;width: 500px;">
<h2 class="text-center">Inicio de sesión</h2>
<p id="mensaje" style="color:red;"></p>
<form action="login_data.php" role="form" name="miForm" method="post"  class="form-in-line" >
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fusu" style="font-size: 18px;"><span id="tuUsu"></span>Usuario</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fusu" name="fusu" placeholder="usuario" onfocus="this.value='';this.style.borderColor='';"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fcontra" style="font-size: 18px;" ><span id="contra"></span>Contraseña</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="fcontra" name="fcontra" placeholder="contraseña" onfocus="this.value='';this.style.borderColor='';"/>
        </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <p><a href="recPassword.php" style="text-decoration: none;">¿Olvidó su contraseña?</a></p>
        </div>
    <div class="form-group text-left">
        <input type="button" value="Enviar datos"  name="enviar" id="mostraenvio" size=25 class="btn btn-primary float-left"  onclick="testear();"/>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Las funciones javascript:

```
        function peticion_login(){
        var miObjeto=new XMLHttpRequest();
        miObjeto.onreadystatechange=function(){

            if(this.readyState==4 && this.status==200){
                document.getElementById("login").innerHTML=this.responseText;
            }
        };
        miObjeto.open("GET",'html_login.php',true);
        miObjeto.send();
    }

    function testear(){
        var b=true;

        var miUsuario=document.miForm.fusu.value;
        var patronUsuario=/^([A-Z a-z]{2,})+$/;
        var resultadoUsuario=patronUsuario.test(miUsuario);

        if(resultadoUsuario==true){
            document.miForm.fusu.style.borderColor="green";
            document.getElementById("tuUsu").innerHTML="";
        }
        else{
            document.miForm.fusu.style.borderColor="red";
            document.getElementById("tuUsu").innerHTML="*";
            document.getElementById("tuUsu").style.color = "red";
            b=false;
        }

        var miContrasenia=document.miForm.fcontra.value;
        var patronContrasenia=/^([0-9A-Z a-z0-9]{2,})+$/;
        var resultadoContrasenia=patronContrasenia.test(miContrasenia);

        if(resultadoContrasenia==true){
            document.miForm.fcontra.style.borderColor="green";
            document.getElementById("contra").innerHTML="";
        }
        else{
            document.miForm.fcontra.style.borderColor="red";
            document.getElementById("contra").innerHTML="*";
            document.getElementById("contra").style.color = "red";
            b=false;
        }

        if(b==true){ 

            alert(" sus datos se enviarán correctamente ");

            document.miForm.enviar.style.display='';
            document.getElementById("login").innerHTML="";
            document.miForm.submit();

            comprar();

    }
    else{ document.getElementById("mensaje").innerHTML="Corrija sus errores, por favor.";}
    }


    function comprar(){

        var miObjeto=new XMLHttpRequest();
        miObjeto.onreadystatechange=function(){

            if(this.readyState==4 && this.status==200){
                document.getElementById("comprar").innerHTML=this.responseText;

            }
        };
        miObjeto.open("GET",'comprar.php',true);
        miObjeto.send();
    }
```

El archivo php:

```
$servidor='localhost';
$usuario='root';
$password='';
$bd='catalogo';
$conne=mysqli_connect($servidor,$usuario,$password,$bd) or die('problemas en la conexión'.mysqli_connect_error());
$sql="select * from users where fusu='$_REQUEST[fusu]' and fcontra='$_REQUEST[fcontra]'";
$resul=mysqli_query($conne,$sql) or die ("problemas con la consulta ".mysqli_error($conne));
if ($reg=mysqli_fetch_array($resul)) {
        header("Location:catalogo_index.php");
}
else{
    echo "<h2 style='margin:100px;text-align:center;'> Usuario no existe</h2>";
}
mysqli_close($conne);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lo que quieres hacer no se puede hacer sin volver a mandar los datos del formulario.
Yo usaría una sesión php en el servidor, de manera que en el archivo html_login.php creas la sessión y almacenas que se ha logueado correctamente:

```
if ($reg=mysqli_fetch_array($resul)) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['login'] = TRUE;
    header("Location:catalogo_index.php");
}
```

Y luego en el archivo catalogo_index.php, al principio indicar que usas la sesión poninendo al principio del archivo:

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
```

Y en ese mismo archivo:

```
<div id="comprar">
    <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION['login'] && $_SESSION['login']==TRUE) {
            require_once('comprar.php');
    }
</div>
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder. Al poner todo esto que me comentas, me sale el siguiente error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of undefined

Comment: Pon algo más de información del error ¿cuándo te sale dicho error?...

Comment: Ay si, perdona. Le pongo el usuario y le doy al entrar, la página recarga pues desaparece el formulario pero no recarga la vista ajax comprar(). Le dí a inspeccionar y me salía este error. Así te sirve o necesitas algo mas?
Y muchas gracias por estar ayudándome.

Comment: No te indica qué línea de código da ese error?

Comment: Me sale esto:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of undefined
    at testear (catalogo_index.php:93)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (VM2303 catalogo_index.php:1)

después del alert de la función testear()

Comment: Eso quiere decir que document.miForm no existe. Algo no se te está cargando.

Comment: Si cambio la función testear de archivo html_login.php, no sale el error pues es la que se carga con ajax, pero entonces me encuentro que no debe entrar en el action del formulario por que ponga el usuario que ponga, entra igualmente a la vista comprar....no se como resolver este conflicto

Comment: Estoy viendo que haces esto: document.miForm.submit(); y luego llamas a comprar(). Esto es un error porque al hacer submit en el formulario te va a llevar al archivo que tiene el formulario en el action y no va a llamar a la función comprar.

Comment: Creo que la lógica de tu programa no está bien planteada, deberías revisarla desde el principio.

Comment: Resolví eliminando la función testear, le puse unos requireds a los campos del formulario, pues tampoco necesitaba tanto rollo de validación e hice el submit normal con su botón del formulario. Ahora va perfecto. 
Muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda, lo de la sesión resolvió el problema principal.

Comment: Me alegro que te funcione, vota la respuesta si te ayudo.

Comment: Gracias por todo!!